# How to increase the width of hidden linear layers in Mistral 7B model?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, attention-model, mistral-7b

After installing

```
!pip install -U bitsandbytes
!pip install -U transformers
!pip install -U peft
!pip install -U accelerate
!pip install -U trl
```

And then some boilerplates to load the Mistral model:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig,HfArgumentParser,TrainingArguments,pipeline, logging
from peft import LoraConfig, PeftModel, prepare_model_for_kbit_training, get_peft_model
from datasets import load_dataset
from trl import SFTTrainer

import torch

bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(  
    load_in_4bit= True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type= "nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype= torch.bfloat16,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant= False,
)

base_model="mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1"


model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        base_model,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        device_map="auto",
        trust_remote_code=True,
)
model.config.use_cache = False # silence the warnings
model.config.pretraining_tp = 1
model.gradient_checkpointing_enable()

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model, trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.padding_side = 'right'
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.add_eos_token = True
tokenizer.add_bos_token, tokenizer.add_eos_token
```

We can see the layers/architecture:

```
>>> model
```

[out]:

```
MistralForCausalLM(
  (model): MistralModel(
    (embed_tokens): Embedding(32000, 4096)
    (layers): ModuleList(
      (0-31): 32 x MistralDecoderLayer(
        (self_attn): MistralAttention(
          (q_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=False)
          (k_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=False)
          (v_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=False)
          (o_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=False)
          (rotary_emb): MistralRotaryEmbedding()
        )
        (mlp): MistralMLP(
          (gate_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4096, out_features=14336, bias=False)
          (up_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4096, out_features=14336, bias=False)
          (down_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=14336, out_features=4096, bias=False)
          (act_fn): SiLU()
        )
        (input_layernorm): MistralRMSNorm()
        (post_attention_layernorm): MistralRMSNorm()
      )
    )
    (norm): MistralRMSNorm()
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=32000, bias=False)
)
```

### Is there any way to increase the width size of the Linear4bit layers?

E.g. if we want the model to take in another 800 more hidden nodes layer to get

```
MistralForCausalLM(
  (model): MistralModel(
    (embed_tokens): Embedding(32000, 4896)
    (layers): ModuleList(
      (0-31): 32 x MistralDecoderLayer(
        (self_attn): MistralAttention(
          (q_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4896, out_features=4896, bias=False)
          (k_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4896, out_features=1024, bias=False)
          (v_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4896, out_features=1024, bias=False)
          (o_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4896, out_features=4896, bias=False)
          (rotary_emb): MistralRotaryEmbedding()
        )
        (mlp): MistralMLP(
          (gate_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4896, out_features=14336, bias=False)
          (up_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=4896, out_features=14336, bias=False)
          (down_proj): Linear4bit(in_features=14336, out_features=4896, bias=False)
          (act_fn): SiLU()
        )
        (input_layernorm): MistralRMSNorm()
        (post_attention_layernorm): MistralRMSNorm()
      )
    )
    (norm): MistralRMSNorm()
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=4896, out_features=32000, bias=False)
)
```

Note: It’s okay if the additional hidden nodes in the `Linear4bit` be randomly initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `hidden_size` parameter in the `MistralConfig` and pass it as an argument when you load the model. [doc](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.38.2/en/model_doc/mistral#transformers.MistralConfig)

It will **not load the pretrained weights in the default parameters** and you may have to retrain the model from scratch. Here's a modified boilerplate:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig,HfArgumentParser,TrainingArguments,pipeline, logging
from peft import LoraConfig, PeftModel, prepare_model_for_kbit_training, get_peft_model
from datasets import load_dataset
from trl import SFTTrainer

import torch

bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(  
    load_in_4bit= True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type= "nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype= torch.bfloat16,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant= False,
)

base_model="mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1"

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(base_model, hidden_size=4896)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        base_model,
        config=config,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        device_map="auto",
        trust_remote_code=True,
        ignore_mismatched_sizes=True # Since we make changes to architecture sizes.
)

model.config.use_cache = False # silence the warnings
model.config.pretraining_tp = 1
model.gradient_checkpointing_enable()

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model, trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.padding_side = 'right'
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.add_eos_token = True
tokenizer.add_bos_token, tokenizer.add_eos_token
```

**Note:** Make sure you add the `ignore_mismatched_sizes=True` argument when initializing `AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained()` when you change the model architecture sizes.

Comment: There's a gotcha in the answer =)

Comment: Added the `ignore_mismatched_sizes` then the code would work.